# Nexus uses old version after upgrade

Tags: nexus

I am using Nexus OSS (v2.5.1-01) on a Windows 7 Enterprise Environment (x86). As this is a very old version I wanted to update it to the newest version (2.11.1-01).

As I had nothing to do with the installation and configuration of the original system, managing the Nexus is a quite new task for me. But it seemed to be quite easy as I only had to download the newest version, and unzip it in the Nexus home directory ([official Sonatype post](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/39180497)). As far as I read it correctly there were no manual steps in the upgrade notes [link](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21701998-nexus-upgrade-notes) that I had to follow.

So far, so good. I downloaded it and unzipped it in our Nexus folder ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Sonatype Nexus\") now I had three folders in this directory:

- sonatype-work
- nexus-2.5.1-01
- nexus-2.11.1-01

Nothing happened, so I restarted the server (In CMD: ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Sonatype Nexus\nexus-2.5.1-01\bin\nexus.bat" stop and ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Sonatype Nexus\nexus-2.11.1-01\bin\nexus.bat" start). The server started, but it still had the old version number.

One thing that looks weird for me was, that in $NEXUS/sonatype-work/nexus/conf/nexus.xml there is an attribute 2.5.1-01. 
But when I change it to "2.11.1-01" and restart the server, it starts, but still has the old version number.

As far as I looked for help in the Internet I couldn't find anyone with this problems, so I'm thinking, that I maybe did something wrong. Does anyone have an idea, what it could be?

Comment: I have some additional information: After changing the version number in nexus.xml and restarting the server, the version number changes back to the old one... I also tried to remove the 2.5.1-01 folder, then change the version number and restart the server, but then I get and error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change the version number in `nexus.xml`. Under Windows you need to go to the directory of the old version of Nexus (`nexus-2.5.1-01`) and execute:

```
bin\jsw\windows-x86-64\stop-nexus.bat
bin\jsw\windows-x86-64\uninstall-nexus.bat
```

And then in `nexus-2.11.1-01`:

```
bin\jsw\windows-x86-64\install-nexus.bat
bin\jsw\windows-x86-64\start-nexus.bat
```

(Obviously, this is for x64. If you're running on a 32-bit machine, you'd have to change to the respective path).

Also, you should restore all the changes you made manually to resources which contained the version string. This is definitely not the way to upgrade Nexus (and may cause problems).

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but I had to restart the VM because of exceptions that the port would be blocked... but after a restart everything was working fine.